# java BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java, stream

```
package byte_base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileViewer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("FileViewerln.txt");

            while((a = fis.read())!=-1){
                System.out.write(a);

            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println(ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

It is Program, printing text from file.
When I used FileInputStream Class and System.out.write() method, It run very well.

But I tried another way.
I used BufferedOutputStream instead of System.out.write() method.

The bottom is code using BufferedOutputStream class.

```
package byte_base;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyOfFileViewer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("FileViewerln.txt");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out);

            while((a = fis.read())!=-1){
                bos.write(a);
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println(ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

But this code's result is vacuum.

I think that first code and second code is very similar.

Why did NOT it(Second Code) working well?

Comment: What does not work about it? Try and add this after your while loop finishes: `bos.flush();`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close OutputStream `bos`.

```
bos.close();
```

Actually It's much better to do your operations in try-with-resources

```
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("FileViewerln.txt");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out);
    ) {
        while((a = fis.read())!=-1){
            bos.write(a);
        }
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        System.err.println(ioe);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

class `InputStream` implements `Closeable`. So its subclasses could be used in try-with-resources.

Comment: That's the actual answer, closing the stream flushes the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Ah the age old `flush` and the `Buffered Stream` question.

Use the flush method.

Place it after the while loop

`bos.flush();`

From the docs

> The class implements a buffered output stream. By setting up such an
>   output stream, an application can write bytes to the underlying output
>   stream without necessarily causing a call to the underlying system for
>   each byte written.

The key point here is

> without necessarily causing a call to the underlying system for each
>   byte written.

That basically means the data is buffered in memory and not written to the output stream on each `write` method call.

You should flush the buffer at a suitable interval and close the stream using the `close` method to force the final buffer out.